# Array printing results from data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm having trouble thinking of a JS function for the following idea. I want to have an array with 5 names. I also want to have a input box with a submit button. When I enter a number (1-5) I want to have it print the name that is assigned with that number from the array. Any ideas?

I have the button/input box setup but I'm not sure how the code would work.

Comment: `java != javascript`

Comment: Too many ideas (question is "too broad"), but top two for communication: **Form** `POST` (or `GET`), or **Ajax** `GET`. --- Top idea for server: Servlet code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? JSFiddle attached https://jsfiddle.net/kgLnc6nd/

HTML

```
<input id='i1'/><br>
<button onclick='javascript:show()'>Click</button><br>
<div id='d1'></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var names = ['michael','henry','james','rebecca','allison'];
function show() {
  var x = i1.value;
    d1.innerHTML = names[x];
}
```

Comment: Sort of. I'm looking to assign each name a numerical value. Then when i type a number in the input box, I want it to print the name, and all the names below that number.